# Cannot create .java in {My Project}: This template did not produce a Java class or an interface

Tags: java, android-studio, interface, extends

Couldn't able to create in my current android studio 3.0.1 I got this error.

I tried to rebuild, Sync and Invalidate catch/ restart as well still I didn't found solution.

here is the error : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OMzw.png